# Calling an HTTPS WCF service with Anonymous authentication?

Tags: wcf, iis

Even though anonymous access is enabled on the Virtual Directory of the WCF service and Integrated Authentication is disabled, I still get the error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

This is what the security definition on client binding configuration looks like:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
</security>
```

And the endpoint definition:

```
<endpoint address="https://url.com/Service.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="spn" />
            </identity>
</endpoint>
```

I've already tried adding:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =  System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there something on IIS that I need to change?

[EDIT]

Service configuration:

```
<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="defaultBehavior"/>
   </endpointBehaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="metadataSupport">
         <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl=""/>
         <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
               <add scheme="https" port="443" />
            </defaultPorts>
         </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
   <service name="ServiceLibrary.Service"
            behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="wsSecureBinding"
                contract="ServiceLibrary.IService"/>
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="wsSecureBinding"
                name="mexHttps"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
</services>
<bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="wsSecureBinding">
         <security mode="Transport"/>
      </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: And what binding configuration are you using on service side?

Comment: I've added the service configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your binding configuration in service to:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsSecureBinding">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

It expects Windows credentials by default.

Comment: we are migrating our old solution to a new server on windows server 2019. the old server already has this binding set and works, however when we replicated every thing on the new server and enabled Anonymous authentication from IIS we still get the error  "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'." we are trying to connect via https